# Activiti : no processes deployed with key

Tags: java, activiti

I get an exception `no processes deployed with key 'Process_MohitWorkflow'` while executing:

```
ProcessInstance instance =
runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey(workflowName, businessKey, variables);
```

I do have an entry in my `act_re_procdef` table for this workflow

> "Process_MohitWorkflow:1:14";1;"http://www.activiti.org/processdef";"Mohit
>   Trust";"Process_MohitWorkflow";1;"11";"MyBPMN.bpmn20.xml";"MyBPMN.Process_MohitWorkflow.png";"";FALSE;TRUE;1;"603"

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

I deployed my `MyBPMN.bpmn20.xml` file using the following code:

```
      public void deployProcessFile(String name, InputStream io, long tenantId) {
        RepositoryService repositoryService = processEngine.getRepositoryService();
        repositoryService.createDeployment()
                .addInputStream(name, io)
                .name(name.substring(0, name.indexOf(".")))
                .enableDuplicateFiltering()
                .tenantId(String.valueOf(tenantId))
                .deploy();
      }
```

**StackTrace:**

```
Caused by: org.activiti.engine.ActivitiObjectNotFoundException: no processes deployed with key 'Process_MohitWorkflow'
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.deploy.DeploymentManager.findDeployedLatestProcessDefinitionByKey(DeploymentManager.java:125)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.cmd.StartProcessInstanceCmd.execute(StartProcessInstanceCmd.java:79)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.cmd.StartProcessInstanceCmd.execute(StartProcessInstanceCmd.java:37)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvoker.execute(CommandInvoker.java:24)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContextInterceptor.execute(CommandContextInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.LogInterceptor.execute(LogInterceptor.java:31)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:35)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.RuntimeServiceImpl.startProcessInstanceByKey(RuntimeServiceImpl.java:81)
    at com.vernuso.trust.server.service.ProcessService.startWorkFlowInstanceForEntity(ProcessService.java:265)
    at com.vernuso.trust.server.service.ProcessService.startOnboardingForOrganisation(ProcessService.java:221)
    at com.google.inject.persist.jpa.JpaLocalTxnInterceptor.invoke(JpaLocalTxnInterceptor.java:70)
    at com.vernuso.trust.server.governance.client.OnboardOrganisationActionHandler.executeTransaction(OnboardOrganisationActionHandler.java:44)
    at com.vernuso.trust.server.governance.client.OnboardOrganisationActionHandler.executeTransaction(OnboardOrganisationActionHandler.java:25)
    at com.vernuso.trust.server.SecuredActionHandler.execute(SecuredActionHandler.java:31)
    at com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rpc.server.AbstractDispatchImpl.doExecute(AbstractDispatchImpl.java:154)
    ... 48 more
```

Any thoughts on what I might be missing?

Regards.

Comment: are you able to start the workflow using: startProcessInstanceByKey(String processDefinitionKey)?

Comment: @flavio.donze No, I get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue by using:

```
ProcessInstance instance = runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey(
  workflowName, businessKey, variables, tenantId);
```

Instead of:

```
ProcessInstance instance = runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey(
  workflowName, businessKey, variables);
```

Initially, I was relying only on:

`processEngine.getRepositoryService().createProcessDefinitionQuery()
    .processDefinitionTenantId(tenantId)
    .singleResult()`

to filter out the processes based on tenantId but I guess it was not sufficient.

Not sure how this works(why we must provide extra param i.e. tenantId to startProcessInstance) or what I should have done to see this before posting here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to deploy subprocess along with original process:

```
 repositoryService.createDeployment()
                .addClasspathResource("diagrams/Process.bpmn")
                .deploy();

 repositoryService.createDeployment()
                .addClasspathResource("diagrams/Process_Subprocess.bpmn")
                .deploy();
```

I am doing this in junit and its working now.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason you might not be able to start your process using `RuntimeService::startProcessInstanceById()` is that the id required as input to that method is not the same as the `id` attribute in your xml file. Activiti refers to the latter as the key instead.

`RuntimeService::startProcessInstanceById()` expects the String id that was generated at deploy time by the Activiti engine. The format of the generated id is `key:version`.